# How to add onclick event to google maps infowindow with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have infowindows on my google maps and I want to call a function called "addToShortlist" whenever a user clicked on the heart icon inside the infowindow. I tried this method first:

```
let html = `<div class="map-infobox">
<span id=${school.schoolID} onclick="addToShortlist(this.id)">
<i title="heart-icon"></i>
</span>
</div>`
window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
      infowindow.setContent(html);
      infowindow.open(this.map, this);
    });
```

It works fine but addToShortlist is outside of react's scope. I want to be able to use a function inside react so that I can update component's state and stuff. 
Then I tried:

```
 ReactDOMServer.renderToString()
```

But it only renders to string and all the js onclick handlers won't work at all.

I think react-google-maps might solve my issue but I already built my project without that library. Is there anyway to accomplish this without using react-google-maps? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this? I am kind of stuck at similar problem, and I can't even use render inplace of renderToString because of in-place props I am passing.

Comment: No, unfortunately we didn't find a solution and we switched to react-google-maps library. Sure enough that library is not perfect and we ran into some other minor issues but it solved the trouble we encountered in the original post.